# virtualapp/didlogical credential in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, credentials

In the Windows 7 credential manager, what is the virtualapp/didlogical credential for?

Answer (score 2):

Those are credentials required for the programs that are needed to be authenticated before they could start..You might want to read this:
http://www.techrena.net/windows/remove-virtualapp-didlogical-credentials-windows-7/